# CFLint tool coldfusion(CFLint VS Fortify)

Tags: coldfusion, cflint

I have scanned coldfusion code using the cflint jar CFLint-1.3.0-1ll.jar from the command line as

`java -jar <jar path> -folder <mylocalColdfusioncodeFolder>`

It gives `cflint-result.html` file in the corresponding folder.
In the report, I found that no cross site scripting and DOM related issues as mentioned by Fortify Audit Workbench tool. CFLint is basically gives language specific issues because it's mainly run on CFParser.

When I run the below command to know the rules against scan I found all are language specific rules.

`java -jar CFLint-1.3.0-all.jar -rules` gives a list of rules as

```
The Supported rules to check against the cfm code :
-----------------------------------------------------
1   ComplexBooleanExpressionChecker
2   GlobalLiteralChecker
3   CFBuiltInFunctionChecker
4   CreateObjectChecker
5   CFDumpChecker
6   FunctionTypeChecker
7   ArrayNewChecker
8   LocalLiteralChecker
9   SelectStarChecker
10  TooManyFunctionsChecker
11  QueryParamChecker
12  FunctionLengthChecker
13  OutputParmMissing
14  WriteDumpChecker
15  CFExecuteChecker
16  ComponentLengthChecker
17  GlobalVarChecker
18  CFModuleChecker
19  CFIncludeChecker
20  CFDebugAttributeChecker
21  ComponentDisplayNameChecker
22  ArgVarChecker
23  NestedCFOutput
24  VarScoper
25  FunctionHintChecker
26  ArgumentNameChecker
27  TooManyArgumentsChecker
28  SimpleComplexityChecker
29  TypedQueryNew
30  CFInsertChecker
31  StructKeyChecker
32  BooleanExpressionChecker
33  VariableNameChecker
34  MethodNameChecker
35  AbortChecker
36  ComponentNameChecker
37  UnusedArgumentChecker
38  StructNewChecker
39  PackageCaseChecker
40  CFAbortChecker
41  ComponentHintChecker
42  ArgumentTypeChecker
43  CFUpdateChecker
44  IsDebugModeChecker
45  ArgDefChecker
46  UnusedLocalVarChecker
47  CFSwitchDefaultChecker
48  ArgumentHintChecker
49  CFCompareVsAssignChecker

-----------------------------------------------------
```

And I found that CFLint does not raises errors of CSS attacks. When I run the same coldfusioncodefolder with Fortify tool (Audit workbench), I got CSS issues like

```
Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected
, Cross-Site Scripting: DOM 
, Unreleased resource
, Dynamic Code Evaluation: Code Injection
, Hardcoded Password
, Sql Injection
, Path Manipulation
, log forging and privacy violation with the tags cfdocument
, cfdirectoryexists
, cfcookie
, cflog
, cffile.....
```

Can you please clarify whether CFLint scans CSS issues or it only checks the rules only specific to ColdFusion language?

Answer (score 1):

CFLint is only concerned about ColdFusion code. It is not a security scanner nor a CSS linter. You are mixing up your tools and their purposes.

A linter scans for code issues - not security issues.

Comment: Hi @Jim, do we have any other code analyzer tool to scan the static coldfusion code.

Comment: Unfortunately ColdFusion doesn't have very good tool support.  What exactly are you trying to scan for?

Comment: Hi Jim, Thank you for the response, I need coldfusion static code analyzer tool to scan the CFM project. As provided in the link https://github.com/cflint/CFLint,
I could run the command on folder base only in command prompt, -jar CFLint-1.5.0-all.jar -folder <baseFolder>, not able to run on enitre project and for
few folder this tool raises errors and does not generate reports. Searching for the tool from last 1 month, any help from your side is appreciated, we need a basic tool only for sample reports.

Comment: Try scanning one folder at a time.  Again ColdFusion is very difficult to parse and often times the linter will fail when scanning too much. Scan one folder at a time and figure out where it's breaking.  Then address those issues and continue scanning.

You can also tell the linter what issues you want to check for - ie scan for cfdumps in the code.

Comment: TQ, Is there a command to tell the linter to scan particular issues. Searching for this.

Comment: I'd suggest... reading the manual (on Github).  And then hopping on CFML Slack. There is a channel there for cflint.